# creating hash from array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array that I want to convert into a hash table. Basically, I want `@array[0]` to be the keys of the hash, and `@array[1]` to be the values of the hash. Is there an easy way to do this in perl? The code I have so far is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

unless( open(INFILE, "<", 'scratch/Drosophila/fb_synonym_fb_2014_05.tsv')) {
die "Cannot open file for reading: ", $!;

while(<INFILE>) {
my @values = split();
#convert values[0] to keys, values[1] to values
}
```

the file is available for download  [here](ftp://ftp.flybase.net/releases/FB2014_05/dmel_r6.02/fasta/)

Comment: `@array[0]` is a one-element slice containing `$array[0]`. Do you mean `@{ $array[0] }`?

Comment: Unclear question. We can only guess what you try to do unless you provide more info, e.g. whats inside `@array`.

Comment: @inferno I apologize I asked the question in haste, I have added my code to help clarify.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! These shouldn't be commented.

Comment: `%hash = map { split } <>`

Comment: @Matt Jacob, If there's only two fields per line.

Comment: @ikegami True, but I'm not about to download a GB of data from an FTP server in order to find out.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The question shows research effort, is useful and clear.

Comment: If there's truly GB of data, you'll probably need a 64-bit build of Perl to have enough addressable space. You'll also need quite a lot of RAM to avoid extreme performance degredation from swapping.

Comment: @Zaid Look at the edit history for the original question, which is probably where the downvotes were accumulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@array[0]` (an array slice, used to return multiple elements) is a bad way of writing `$array[0]` (an array lookup, used to return a single element). `use warnings;` would have told you this.

---

To set a hash element, one uses

```
$hash{$key} = $val;
```

So the code becomes

```
my %hash;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\t/;
    $hash{ $fields[0] } = $fields[1];
}
```

Better yet,

```
my %hash;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split /\t/;
    $hash{$key} = $val;
}
```

---

The name of the file implies the fields are tab-separated, not whitespace separated, so I switched

```
split ' '
```

to

```
split /\t/
```

This required the addition of `chomp`.